# Why Ohm’s law doesn’t work in these scenarios (inside ideal battery and in vacuum)?

Tags: electricity, electric-current, electrical-resistance, batteries

**Scenario 1 - Ideal battery**

Suppose I have an ideal battery whose electrolyte’s resistance is zero. In the working battery there will be current flowing inside the battery also (due to battery forces) from lower potential to higher potential. Now I choose two points inside the battery, one on the positive terminal and other on the negative terminal now there is current between these two points so I apply Ohm’s law $V=IR$. Now $V$ is non zero(since my points lie on the terminals) and $R$ is zero, which is not in accordance with Ohm’s law.

**Scenario 2 - Current in vacuum**

Suppose in vacuum there are two pints which are at different potentials and let there be a beam of electrons travelling from the point which is at lower potential to the other. Now since it’s vacuum $R=0$ but $V$ is non zero which is again not in accordance with Ohm’s law.

I may be wrong somewhere in my understanding of Ohm’s law since I’m a new learner. Please correct me so that I can understand it well enough.

Comment: Why do you assume R=0 in a vacuum? I'd expect $R=\infty$ is a better approximation for many situations.

Comment: Re the battery: isn't the electric field due to the charge on the terminals screened by ion distribution in the electrolyte?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite the name, Ohm’s law is not a general law of nature. It is instead a defining characteristic of a small class of materials and devices called resistors (and conductors). Ohm’s law does not apply to other materials and devices, including insulators, capacitors, inductors, switches, transistors, vacuum, voltage sources, current sources, dielectrics, semiconductors, and many others. All of these devices and materials violate Ohm’s law.

All of that is to say that you are correct that both batteries and vacuum violate Ohm’s law.

Comment: by conductors do you mean only the metallic ones or electrolytic also.

Comment: namely ohmic resistors (conductors) at that

Comment: "Ohm's law does not apply to ...insulators". Ohm's law is used in various testing standards to determine the volume resistivity of polymeric insulating materials. For example:https://www.nts.com/services/testing/materials/volume-and-surface-resistivity/#:~:text=Volume%20Resistivity%20and%20Surface%20Resistivity%20Testing%20Techniques.%20Resistivity,Using%20Ohm%E2%80%99s%20law%20to%20calculate%20the%20observed%20resistance

Comment: @Bob D from the very site you mention “The amount of voltage applied to the material greatly alters the test’s final results”. This indicates that they strongly deviate from Ohm’s law.

Comment: I'm just saying Ohm's law is used to determine insulation resistance in a specific test. That doesn't mean the relationship is linear over any range of voltage. That's the case even for so called "resistors". I'm just bringing it to your attention. You can take it for what it's worth.